# Set different logout time for different users in django?

Tags: django, session, django-rest-framework, django-views

Can anyone know how to set session timeout per user in Django? I'm building a system where I need to set a user timeout session, if a user is failed to perform any action till a timeout setting then he will be logout of the system.
Is this possible in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can use `request.session.set_expiry(<VALUE>)` in your login view to dynamically set session expiry based on some rule

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry